# Best approach to handle 8-12 cameras through one PC?

Tags: video-camera, webcam, camera

For a more complex project I need to process the video input of 8 to 12 cameras at the same time on a single computer but each with a rather low resolution (probably 480p). Those cameras could either be simple USB cameras or ones with analogue output so some converter is required.

The actual processing should happen through a self written program in C++.

The focus is on low cost for the setup (without the computer) and if possible, low latency as well.

So far I thought to use simple, cheap USB consumer webcams. Would that be the best way?

There are all kinds of camera modules Alibaba and similar shops like this one: http://www.banggood.com/Eachine-Falcon-250-13-CMOS-700TVL-110-Degree-FPV-Camera-p-1040713.html
However, I couldn't find a proper way to connect multiple of them to a PC to process the analogue signal digitally.

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to figure out what type of hardware you need by yourself, then come back to us when you know that.

Comment: Eh, once I've bought the hardware, I wont really need any help anymore...
However, will figure it out myself, I guess.